# Drupal: how to set collapsed property for edit-content fields

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-fapi

is there any interface to decide which fields should be collapsed and which ones not in content pages ?

i.e. Tags is collapsed
Menu Settings is expanded, Authoring is expanded..

I would like the opposite.
thanks

**Updated**:
Taxonomy super-select field (how can I refer to this field ('taxonomy' is not working))

```
<div class="taxonomy-super-select-checkboxes"><fieldset class=" collapsible collapsed"><legend class="collapse-processed"><a href="#">Tags</a></legend><div class="fieldset-wrapper"><div id="edit-taxonomy-tags-1-wrapper" class="form-item">
 <label for="edit-taxonomy-tags-1">Enter New Tags: </label>
 <input type="text" class="form-text form-autocomplete" value="" size="60" id="edit-taxonomy-tags-1" name="taxonomy[tags][1]" maxlength="1024" autocomplete="OFF">
 <div class="description">A comma-separated list of terms describing this content. Example: funny, bungee jumping, "Company, Inc.".</div>
</div><input type="hidden" disabled="disabled" value="http://localhost/drupal/taxonomy/autocomplete/1" id="edit-taxonomy-tags-1-autocomplete" class="autocomplete autocomplete-processed"><div id="edit-taxonomy-1-20-wrapper" class="form-item">
 <label for="edit-taxonomy-1-20" class="option"><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="20" id="edit-taxonomy-1-20" name="taxonomy[1][20]"> Tag1</label>
</div></div>

</fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the interface to Drupal's collapsible fieldsets is the [Drupal Forms API](http://drupal.org/node/751826) [`#collapsed` property](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#collapsed). if this property is set to `TRUE`, the fieldset is collapsed, and vice versa. to change the defaults, *don't hack core files*, but do it (one of) the Drupal way(s) and add this to your `template.php`:

```
function phptemplate_node_form($form) {
  $form['taxonomy']['#collapsed'] = false;
  $form['menu']['#collapsed'] = true;
  $form['author']['#collapsed'] = true;
  // etc. for all fieldsets you want to change
  return drupal_render($form);
}
```

after this, you should [clean the theme registry](http://drupal.org/node/173880#theme-registry).

Comment: ok cool, it works thanks. Still one question, I'm using taxonomy super-select module, so the taxonomy identifier doesn't work in my form. Where can I get the ids (such as taxonomy, menu.. etc for all modules ?) I've added the html code of the taxonomy super select form field in the question.

Comment: to get the form ids, you have to check the source code. search for `#collapsed` and see if the array where this property is set is the one you want to change. in the case of Taxonomy Super Select this is a little complicated as there appear to be multiple and dynamic fieldsets. just experiment a little and add some `var_dump()`s here and there. good luck!